# Devise before_action : authentication exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am running devise. I want everything to force sign-in except a specific route. In my app I'm saving a long url and using a short url to point back to my app to grab the long url for a redirect. An external user that is not logged in needs to be able to follow that short url back and grab the long url for an external redirect.  for example localhost.com/WdeFrs pulls the long link from the database and redirects to the site....google.com as example. Everything works except when you follow the link back it forces a login. **It needs to work without login** Can someone help clarify the fix. Thank you

*application_controller.rb*

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:urls]
```

*routes.rb*

```
 resources :urls
  get "/:short_url", to: "urls#shortcustom"
  get "shortened/:short_url", to: "urls#shortened", as: :shortened
```

Comment: for which method you dont want login user ?

Comment: get "/:short_url", to: "urls#shortcustom"     I think is what I'm trying to make an exception.

Comment: try this ` skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :shortcustom` in your urls controller.

Comment: Did you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `before_action` option `except` expects an action name, not a controller name. As is, your code is skipping authentication for any action named `urls`.

To skip authentication for `urls#shortcustom` and `urls#shortened`, you need to include

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:shortcustom, :shortened]
```

in your `UrlsController`.

Comment: I did try it and I'm getting and error: in skip_callback': Before process_action callback :authenticate_user! has not been defined (ArgumentError)  I'm looking for the fix to this bug  now. :)

Comment: @Jrinard as the error says, there is no `authenticate_user!` defined within the scope of the controller. Are you sure that it is defined in `ApplicationController`, and that `UrlsController` inherits from that?

Comment: Yes thank you I didn't have before_action :authenticate_user! in my application_controller! 
Thanks for the help!